# Is there a way to call a function stored as a property using bracket notation in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am building an object that contains properties where the key is a string and the value is a function. I understand that if the key was not a string, I could use dot notation to call this function. For example:

```
const obj = new Object();
obj.prop1 = function () {return true}

//what I want to emulate
obj.prop1()
```

In this situation I could just call obj.prop1() to run the function. However, I am adding properties to this object dynamically, and thus need to pass a string when creating properties. Example below:

```
obj['prop1'] = function() {return true}

//Unfortunately I cannot call the function stored in prop1 using the example below
obj['prop1']()
```

How can I call the function using bracket notation?

Comment: Try without the `new Object()`.  Just do `const obj = {};`.  The notation you show should work.

Comment: "//Unfortunately I cannot call the function stored in prop1 using the example below" -> Why not? Have you tried? What errors do you get? The code you show should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written is already the correct method to call the function using bracket notation. See the working snippet below.

```js
const obj = new Object();
obj['prop1'] = function() {return true};
console.log(obj['prop1']());
```